# How to get data between two brackets in this array?

Tags: arrays, regex

I have an html file like this :

```html
{Hello1
<BR>
<BR>
Line#1
<BR>
Line#2
}{Hello2
<BR>
<BR>
Line#1
<BR>
Line#2}{Hello3
<BR>
<BR>
Line#1
<br>
Line#2}
```

I tried to get each data between the {...} and remove these blank lines but I couldn't. Anyone can help me to solve it ? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

## 1st part:

Regex:

```
(?<={)[^}]+(?=})
```

This will match anything after a `{` up to a `}`.

## 2nd part:

Regex:

```
<BR>\n
```

with substitution:

```
<empty>
```

where `<empty>` is nothing.  This will match the `<BR>` then a newline.